# How to extract last 2 periods of data from the table

Tags: sql-server

With the below script i get only last 14 days worth of data which does not work with what i want to achieve, But aiming to getting the data for last 2 periods(last 2 weeks of existing data) from the table, It should fetch complete period(Sun - Sat) irrespective of which day of the week I run the script the out put should return only those 2 periods data.

```sql
SELECT convert(date,convert(varchar(10),Date,110)) AS Date , LocID , EmpID
FROM TableName
WHERE convert(date,convert(varchar(10),Date,110)) 
    < dateadd(day,-(14+day(getdate())),getdate())
```

Comment: Tried this in where  clause too does the same as above , Any suggestons pleaseconvert(varchar(255), cast(cast(date_key as varchar(255)) as date), 101)>=DATEADD(week,-2,GETDATE())

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "irrespective of which day of the week I run the script the out put should return only those 2 periods data". Provide some examples maybe.